# How do I specify in Ruby that I want to match a character provided that a sequence following that character does not match a pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5.1.  In Ruby, how do I say taht I want to match a string if the first character matches something but the sequence that follows does NOT match a pattern?  That is, I want to match a number provided that the sequence taht follows is not a character from an array I have followed by two other numbers.  Here's my character array ...

2.4.0 :010 > TOKENS
 => [":", ".", "'"]

So this string would NOT match

```
3:00
```

since ":00" matches the pattern of a character from my array followed by two numbers.  But this string

```
3400
```

would match.  This string would also match

```
3:0
```

and this would match

```
3
```

since nothing follows the above.  How do I write the appropriate regex in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string =~ /\A\d+(?!:\d{2})/
```

This regular expression means:

- `\A` anchors the match to the *start* of the string.
- `\d+` means "one or more digits".
- `(?!...)` is a *negative look-ahead*. It checks that the pattern contained in the brackets does *not* match., looking ahead from the current position.
- `:\d{2}` means `:` followed by two digits.

Answer (score 0):

Consideration should be given to testing the first character and the remaining characters separately.

```
def match_it?(str, first_char_regex, no_match_regex)
  str[0].match?(first_char_regex) && !str[1..-1].match?(no_match_regex)
end

match_it?("0:00", /0/, /\A[:. ]cat\z/)           #=> true
match_it?("0:00", /\d/, /\A[:. ]\d+\z/)          #=> false
match_it?("0:00", /[[:alpha:]]/, /\A[:. ]\d+\z/) #=> false
```

I believe this reads well and it simplifies testing when compared to methods that employ a single regular expression.

Comment: The question was a little ambiguous: "I want to match **a number**, not followed by...". Your abstraction assumes that "a number" is only *one digit*, whereas the single-regex solution is more generic.

Comment: For example, your method doesn't work well for ensuring that strings like `10:00` **don't** match. It's possible, but IMO more confusing than just performing a single regex to begin with! `match_it?("10:00", /\d/, /\A\d*:\d+\z/)`

Comment: @Tom, you are probably right. I took a literal interpretation of the question, but on re-reading it I see it's internally inconsistent. "a little amiguous"? m' Lord is ever so kind.